# Find the lowest value that is not null using python

Tags: python, min

I have used min(A,B,C,D) in python. This works perfectly in finding the lowest value, however, if I have a null value (0 value) in any of the varaibles A,B,C or D, it would return the null value (or 0). Any ideas how to return the non-null or non-zero value in my case? thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would go with a filter which will handle None, 0, False, etc...

```
>>> min(filter(None, [1, 2, 0, None, 5, False]))
1
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

> > > Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to [item for item in iterable if function(item)] if function is not None and [item for item in iterable if item] if function is None

Answer (score 6):

This pushes any `0` to the other end (max end)

```
min(A, B, C, D, key=lambda x:(x==0, x))
```

Or you can use a generator expression

```
min(x for x in (A, B, C, D) if x)
```

Using filter

```
min(filter(None, (A, B, C, D))
```

Finally, using itertools.compress

```
from itertools import compress
min(compress((A, B, C, D), (A, B, C, D)))
```

Comment: I loved the first solution - took me some time to grok it. You should've explained it in more details, though - for a beginner it would be a total enigma.

Answer (score 1):

```
min(v for v in (A,B,C,D) if not v in (None,0))
```