# Get min value, not null

Tags: python

Is there a better way to do the following pattern?

```
cost = min(t_data.sd_retail_price or 100000, t_data.hd_retail_price or 100000)
```

Basically, I'm looking for the lowest non-null value.

Comment: Is something like this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084714/find-the-lowest-value-that-is-not-null-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
cost = min(x for x in (t_data.sd_retail_price, t_data.hd_retail_price, 100000) if x)
```

If `t_data.sd_retail_price` and `t_data.hd_retail_price` are both None, then you'll be left with 100000 as a result.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cost = min(filter(None, (t_data.sd_retail_price, t_data.hd_retail_price, 100000)))
```